# Is it possible to fetch data from an HTTP URL to Logstash?

Tags: logstash

As title says, I need to feed data(CSV or JSON) directly into logstash. What I want is to set a filter, say CSV, which reads the content directly from some http://example.com/csv.php into Logstash without involving any `middleman` script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to call an http resource repeatedly and fetch data into logstash. So you are looking for an input rather than a filter.

Logstash [has just released](https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-logstash-http-poller) a new [http poller input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http_poller.html) plugin for that purpose. After installing it using `bin/plugin install logstash-input-http_poller` you can set a config like this to call your resource:

```
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
      myresource => "http://example.com/csv.php"
      }
    }
    request_timeout => 60
    interval => 60
    codec => "json" # set this if the response is json formatted
  }
}
```

If the response contains CSV you need to set a [csv filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html).

```
filter {
    csv{ }
}
```

There are also plugins which perform an http request within the filter section. However, these are supposed to enrich an existing event and that doesn't seem to be what you are looking for.

Comment: That's what I am looking for.

Comment: @hurb will this work if i dont want to use interval? like pull data once and then shutdown. plz help

Comment: @myjscoffee No it doesn't work for a one time pull, this is an input that continuously pulls data into logstash. `interval` is deprecated, the new keyword is `schedule` - a required config parameter. You can also use a `http-filter` to trigger a HTTP request for every incoming event. If you want to do one time processing of a http resource, just curl the resource and store the result in a file. Then use the logstash file input to process that file.